# Django Filter Loop OR

Tags: django

Does anyone know how I get Django Filter build an OR statement? I'm not sure if I have to use the Q object or not, I thought I need some type of OR pipe but this doesn't seem right:

```
    filter_mfr_method = request.GET.getlist('filter_mfr_method')
    for m in filter_mfr_method:
        designs = designs.filter(Q(mfr_method = m) | m if m else '')
        # Or should I do it this way?
        #designs = designs.filter(mfr_method = m | m if m else '')
```

I would like this to be:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE mfr_method = 1 OR mfr_method = 2 OR mfr_method = 3
```

**EDIT: Here is what Worked**

```
    filter_mfr_method = request.GET.getlist('filter_mfr_method')
    list = []
    for m in filter_mfr_method:
        list.append(Q(mfr_method = m))

    designs = designs.filter(reduce(operator.or_, list))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
import operator 

filter_mfr_method = request.GET.getlist('filter_mfr_method')
filter_params = reduce(operator.or_, filter_mfr_method, Q())
designs = designs.filter(filter_params)
```

Comment: Man I would never have guessed that. I keep getting a `TypeError, Exception Value 1 ` on this line `filter_params = reduce(operator.or_, filter_mfr_method, Q())` -- Which has to do with the ID's im passing from the `getlist` - Do you know why that is, Im looking up this reduce function at the moment

Comment: `getlist` is probably the problem. I copied it without actually considering what it does. You would probably need to do something like `filter_mfr_method = [{'mfr_method': m} for m in request.GET.getlist('filter_mfr_method')]`

Comment: Thanks man I posted my updated final result in the main message :)

Answer (score 1):

Something I used before:

```
qry = None
for val in request.GET.getlist('filter_mfr_method'):
    v = {'mfr_method': val}
    q = Q(**v)
    if qry: 
        qry = qry | q
    else: 
        qry = q

designs = designs.filter(qry)
```

That is taken from one of my query builders.

Comment: Thanks this is close to what I ended up writing!

Comment: Normally i use this with another loop so it searches different values in different fields (with changing `key-value` of `v`). It is pretty easy for such queries.